# Create Elastic Beanstalk environment using existing resources

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Since EB create resources with weird names it becomes difficult to monitor resources.

I want to create resources with proper names (eg autoscale config, elb etc) & make use of these resources to create EB environment.

Can I do this? If not then what is the best way to achieve sanity in handling so many weird named resources created by EB if i have multiple environments?

Answer (score 1):

Use CloudFormation directly. ElasticBeanstalk, under the hood, simply generates a CloudFormation template and deploys a stack.

By using the CloudFormation template directly, you can name resources as you see fit.

You can look under CloudFormation - Stacks to get a starting point by looking an exact stack template ElasticBeanstalk has already tried to deploy

Comment: but can i create later eb environment from cloudformation? eb is good for deployment